# minikube start error - Failed to validate 'docker' driver

Tags: docker, kubernetes, minikube, docker-toolbox, kubernetes-cluster

How to resolve the following error when I try to do minikube start

minikube v1.12.3 on Microsoft Windows 10 Home Single Language

Using the docker driver based on user configuration

! 'docker' driver reported an issue: "docker version --format {{.Server.Os}}-{{.Server.Version}}" exit status 1: error during connect: Get http://%2F%2F.%2Fpipe%2Fdocker_engine/v1.40/version: open //./pipe/docker_engine: The system cannot find the file specified. In the default daemon configuration on Windows, the docker client must be run elevated to connect. This error may also indicate that the docker daemon is not running.

Suggestion: Start the Docker service. If Docker is already running, you may need to reset Docker to factory settings with: Settings > Reset.

Documentation: https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/1825#issuecomment-450501157

X Failed to validate 'docker' driver

Comment: Please check docker up and running if it is up and running then check docker and minikube version are compatible

Comment: Thanks for your comment, yes my docker is up and running and this is my docker version  : Docker version 19.03.1

Comment: Did you [verify](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/drivers/docker/#troubleshooting) `docker info --format '{{.OSType}}'`  [Switch between Windows and Linux containers](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/#switch-between-windows-and-linux-containers)

Comment: @Mark  Yes, it's Linux. do we need to run and any particular image before starting MiniKube?

Answer (score 0):

Add your non-root user to the docker group and it will have the permission to the docker service.
This fixed the issue for me. Hope it hepls you too.

Answer (score 0):

Try logging in to docker. It solved the same problem I had

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34503958)